# Solr facet performance

Tags: solr

I am working with Solr facet fields and come across a performance problem I don't understand.  Consider these two queries:

1. `q=`**word**`&facet.field=CONTENT&facet=true&facet.prefix=&facet.limit=10&facet.mincount=1&facet.method=enum&rows=0`
2. `q=`**word**`&facet.field=CONTENT&facet=true&facet.prefix=`**a**`&facet.limit=10&facet.mincount=1&facet.method=enum&rows=0`

The only difference is an empty `facet.prefix` in the first query.

The first query returns after some 20 seconds (`QTime` 20000 in the result) while the second one takes only 80 msec (`QTime` 80).  Why is this?

And as side note: `facet.method=fc` makes the queries run 'forever' and eventually fail with `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Too many values for UnInvertedField faceting on field CONTENT`.

This is with Solr 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

From this doc:http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Faceting

> The facet.prefix parameter limits the terms on which to facet to those
>   starting with the given string prefix.

that means that you facet by less terms.
Now, I'm quite sure the faceting time is included in the Qtime (as seems demonstrated by this post: http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg39859.html).

So that means less terms, less time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not facet on CONTENT as this probably has many different terms and makes no sense faceting on. Try faceting on a category field or some other field with less unique terms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing them in the opposite order after a fresh restart of Solr server?

Usually the first query takes more time and if the next queries happen to have more in common with any of the previous, there'd be cache-hits and response time would be incredible.

In addition, please note that 'enum' is more suitable for facet-fields with less number of unique terms within.

Also, try increasing [filter-cache.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache) to a really big number and check your cache-hit ratio at

```
 SOLR_DOMAIN:PORT/solr/#/collection1/plugins/cache?entry=fieldValueCache,filterCache
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried that with our default value, got an answer after 3 minutes.  I then increased `filterCache` ten times, got an answer after 3 minutes.  I then increased `filterCache` another ten times, got an answer after 15 minutes or so.  Got to be something else.